# Keyboard break layout and behaviour

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

I have a fragment with some views like EditText, ViewFlipper and RecyclerView.

But I have an issue with the keyboard: when the keyboard appear, some of my views become whites and my RecyclerView is empty or when I tap on an item I have to scroll him to handle the event.

Do you know why the soft keyboard break the layout and behavior? And do you know how to solve this?

Thanks you for your help.

**EDIT : Seems solved**

I've found a solution which seems to work:

I change the `softInputMode` in the `onCreate()` method to `adjustNothing`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)
}
```

then in `onDestroy` I set the previous mode, here `adjustPan`

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch your Activity's `windowSoftInputMode` flag to `adjustPan` in your `AndroidMainfest.xml` file inside your activity tag.

Check the official documentation for more info.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

```
<activity 
  ... 
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Comment: My activity has already ```android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"```